# Does a monk get cumulative bonuses to proficiency and unarmed movement each level?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, stacking

As a monk levels up, [the monk table](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Monk#content) says they get the following:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Level} & \textbf{Proficiency Bonus} & \textbf{Martial Arts} & \textbf{Unarmored Movement} \\
\hline
\text{1st} & \text{+2} & \text{1d4} & \text{-} \\
\hline
\text{2nd} & \text{+2} & \text{1d4} & \text{+10 ft.} \\
\hline
\text{3rd} & \text{+2} & \text{1d4} & \text{+10 ft.} \\
\hline
\text{4th} & \text{+2} & \text{1d4} & \text{+10 ft.} \\
\hline
\text{5th} & \text{+3} & \text{1d6} & \text{+10 ft.} \\
\hline
\text{6th} & \text{+3} & \text{1d6} & \text{+15 ft.} \\
\hline
\end{array}

Do I add what it says at each level to what I already have?

At level 6, do get add +14 to proficiency? And also, if I started with 30 speed, do I add the movement as well to make my movement be 85 total?

Comment: 5e and as i level up at say 2 i get a +2 to proficiency and +10 to movement and so on and so fourth as the question is do i keep adding those to what i have allready since  i start with 30 movement so i would then add +10 each level so that at level 6 i would be at an 85 movement and 20 to profieciency this was my question or is the wording in this wrong https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Monk#content

Comment: Is your Martial Arts damage also 4d4+2d6?

Comment: no I thought it was just d6  for damage is that wrong as well?

Comment: it _is_ 1d6. But why sum other colums and not Martial Arts?

Comment: @András it seems reasonable to interpret that the plus sign means that it must be added for each level.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The table lists the bonus you have at that level. They are not in addition to the previous levels.

So for a Level 6 Monk, he would have a proficiency bonus of +3, a Martial Arts die of 1d6, and a unarmored movement bonus of +15 (45 ft total).

Note: For a multiclass character, proficiency bonus is based on total character levels not individual class levels.